# Prove that $A/A' \otimes_{R} B/B' \cong (A \otimes_{R} B)/C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

This is an exercise from Algebra, by Hungerford, chapter IV, section 5 problem 5. The problem states:

If $A'$ is a submodule of the right R-module $A$ and $B'$ is a submodule of the left R-module $B$, then $A/A' \otimes_{R} B/B' \cong (A \otimes_{R} B)/C$, where $C$ is the subgroup of $A\otimes_{R} B$ generated by all elements $a'\otimes b$ and $a \otimes b'$ with $a\in A$, $a'\in A'$, $b\in B$, $b'\in B'$.

Clearly one must construct a well-defined homomorphism $f:A/A' \otimes_{R} B/B' \to (A \otimes_{R} B)/C$ and then show it is a bijection. The issue is I don't know what such a function should look like. Any thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to construct homomorphisms
$$ f\colon (A \otimes_R B)/C\to A/A' \otimes_R B/B', \qquad g\colon A/A' \otimes_R B/B' \to (A \otimes_R B)/C $$
that are mutual inverses. The naive way to define then is to map $f([a] \otimes [b])=[a \otimes b]$ and $g([a \otimes b])=[a] \otimes [b]$, but of course this feels a bit sloppy. Why are these maps well defined? Why are they group homomorphisms?

Instead, the idea is to use the universal properties of quotients/tensor products. For instance, let me detail the construction of $g$, and I'll leave $f$ as an exercise.

Recall the following property:

> Let $M$ be a right $R$-module, $N$ a left $R$-module, and $P$ an abelian group. Then for any bilinear, balanced morphism $\phi\colon M \times N \to P$, there exists a unique morphism $\Phi\colon M \otimes_R N \to P$ of abelian groups, satisfying $\Phi(m \otimes n)=\phi(m, n)$.

This result gives us the following idea: we will try to define a balanced, bilinear morphism $\phi\colon A/A' \times B/B' \to (A \otimes_R B)/C$, and then use the property above.

We define $\phi([a], [b])=[a \otimes b]$. Checking that this is well defined is a formal computation. For instance, if $[b_1]=[b_2]$ (i.e. $b_1-b_2=b' \in B'$), then
$$ [a \otimes b_1]-[a \otimes b_2] = [a \otimes b_1-a \otimes b_2]= [a \otimes (b_1-b_2)]= [a \otimes b']=[0], $$
as $a \otimes b' \in C$. It is also well defined in the other coordinate by a similar computation. Also,
$$ \phi([a], [rb])=[a \otimes rb]=[ar \otimes b]= \phi([ar], [b]), $$
showing that $\phi$ is balanced.

We get a bilinear, balanced map $A/A' \times B/B' \to (A \otimes_R B)/C$, which by the property above defines a group homomorphism $g\colon A/A' \otimes_R B/B' \to (A \otimes_R B)/C$, by $g([a], [b])=[a \otimes b]$.

Comment: Why have you used the notation meant for equivalence classes? In other words, why have you used $[\cdot]$ notation?

Comment: Because the elements of $A/A'$ can be though as equivalence classes. Otherwise, you will have to denote e.g. $g(a+A', b+B')=(a \otimes b)+C$.

Comment: Point well taken, I don't know how I missed that . . .

Comment: Is this the more common approach rather than searching for a direct bijection?

Comment: Usually yes! It tends to be difficult to show that the maps are well defined without using the universal properties.